# Unable to set query inside if-statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, cloudkit, ckrecord

Basically I'm attempting to set a specific query in the current table controller depending on the indexpath.row value taken from a previous table controller.  So for example,

```
        if indexpath1 == 1 
        {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "American", predicate: predicate)
        }
        else
        {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Bistro", predicate: predicate)
        }

        publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
```

however, the performquery function comes up with the "use of unresolved indentifier "query".

Do I need to set query to a value before the if-statement to act as a base value that is changed dependant upon the if-statement?  Or I am unable to complete this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a basic scope problem, you create a local query instance inside your if, but that doesn't live on to do any good in this world.

```
var query: CKQuery
if indexpath1 == 1 {
        query = CKQuery(recordType: "American", predicate: predicate)
        }
        else
        {
        query = CKQuery(recordType: "Bistro", predicate: predicate)
        }

        publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
```

Or perhaps a bit more elegant:

```
let recordType = indexpath1 == 1 ? "American" : "Bistro"
let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate)
publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in {
    //...
}
```

Comment: that simple, haha.  Thank you!